# AlertDialog inside another alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an alertdialog with 3 options, one of which opens up another alertdialog with an editext.

the issue is, once the second alertdialog has been opened up I cant manage to finish or end the one prior to it, it stays hidden underneath the second dialog and pops out again when i begin typing in the editext.

```
 void generateAlertDialog(long timeSpent) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                GActivity.this);


        builder.setMessage(
                "The time stayed in the game is " + timeSpent + "s")
                .setTitle("You Lose")
                .setPositiveButton("Reset Game",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                finish();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(GActivity.this,   GActivity.class);
                                Bundle setting = configureGame(RWIDTH, BSIZE, Speed);
                                intent.putExtra("setting", setting);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })
                .setNeutralButton("Score List",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // User clicked score button
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        GActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage(
                                        "Please input the player's name");
                                        setTitle("Score");
                                        final EditText input = new EditText(GActivity.this);
                                        builder.setView(input)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Reset Game",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int id) {

                                                                }

                                                            })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {

                                                                }
                                                            });
                                // 3. Get the AlertDialogfrom create()
                                AlertDialog dialogsnd = builder.create();

                                // 4. Show dialog
                                dialogsnd.show();
                            }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                finish();
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });

        // 3. Get the AlertDialogfrom create()
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        // 4. Show dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: in my opinion for a simpler solution make an activity and open it as dialog with specifying <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" /> over base activity and than open another dialog over it.

Comment: what i do in that situations is make the first or top alertdialog final and dismiss it inside the onclicklistener of the choices but you must call the create() of the top dialog first to be able to do it. and yeah call it in an activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just u need to put dialog.dismiss(); where u want to close alert box(i.e previous one) as below


void generateAlertDialog(long timeSpent) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                GActivity.this);


        builder.setMessage(
                "The time stayed in the game is " + timeSpent + "s")
                .setTitle("You Lose")
                .setPositiveButton("Reset Game",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                finish();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(GActivity.this,   GActivity.class);
                                Bundle setting = configureGame(RWIDTH, BSIZE, Speed);
                                intent.putExtra("setting", setting);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })
                .setNeutralButton("Score List",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {


//------------------> put dialog.dismiss();

dialog.dismiss();
                                // User clicked score button
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        GActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage(
                                        "Please input the player's name");
                                        setTitle("Score");
                                        final EditText input = new EditText(GActivity.this);
                                        builder.setView(input)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Reset Game",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int id) {

                                                                }

                                                            })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {

                                                                }
                                                            });
                                // 3. Get the AlertDialogfrom create()
                                AlertDialog dialogsnd = builder.create();

                                // 4. Show dialog
                                dialogsnd.show();
                            }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                finish();
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });

        // 3. Get the AlertDialogfrom create()
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        // 4. Show dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: nope dialog.dismiss(); will dismiss the dialog but once the 2nd dialog has been created a few seconds later the first one still pops up

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Boolean that calls the previous alert if true. Put the second alert into a new method. When calling the second alert from the first, make sure to put the Boolean for the first into false, dismiss the dialog, then call the second alert. That way the first dialog will never reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Call `dialog.dismiss();` befre creating new Dialog.

Comment: nope dialog.dismiss(); will dismiss the dialog but once the 2nd dialog has been created a few seconds later the first one still pops up

Comment: Your code is fine with `dialog.dismiss();` probably you are calling `generateAlertDialog(..);` multiple times